# changing the location of a star plot label

Tags: r, plot

I am running the following code and need some to get the name ID of each star plot on the middle-top of each one.

```
> u=whisky[1:10,3:14]
> z=as.character(whisky$Distillery)
> color1<-rep(c("peru"),each=nrow(u))
> win.graph(50,40,8)
Error: could not find function "win.graph"
> stars( x=u , locations = NULL , key.loc = c(0,0) , labels=z[1:10],
+        key.labels = colnames(u) , col.lines=1:10, lwd=1 )
> 
> ##sloc <- stars(u,len=0.6,lwd=1,col.stars=color1,labels=z[1:nrow(u)])
> sloc <- stars(u,main="whiskey flavor profiles",col.main=53,full=TRUE,
+               labels=z[1:nrow(u)],col.lab=101,flip.labels=FALSE,len=0.6,lwd=0.3,col.stars=color1,ncol=NULL)
> 
> Map(
+   function(x,y) stars(
+     matrix(1,ncol=ncol(u),nrow=nrow(u)),key.loc=c(x,y),ncol=NULL,
+     key.labels=colnames(u),add=TRUE, lty=3, cex=0.6, len=0.6),
+   sloc$Var1, sloc$Var2
+ )
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You should provide sample input so we can run your code.  Also are you not worried about the `win.graph` error? It would help if you could make a sketch of the desired output.

Comment: ok win.graph (I am not even using because I am using a Mac)

Comment: example http://statofmind.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/generate_image.pdf